# How to detect in autotools what libc uses Linux distributive: glibc, uclibc, musl, etc

Tags: autotools, automake

There are different implementation of some (for example `backtrace`) function in code. This implementation differs depending on libc version. In my case it could be glibc (Debian) or musl libc (openwrt). How to detect what libc is installed in Linux distro?

[Using Autotools for a project with platform specific source code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398632/using-autotools-for-a-project-with-platform-specific-source-code) only detects CPU platform not libc version

Comment: Why do you care which C library version you're building for?  This is a serious question: presumably, there are behavioral differences that you care about, and it is better in pretty much every way to test the specific behaviors that matter to you, rather than to test the library family itself (if that were even possible).

Comment: Or if it's a question of which functions are available, then it is absolutely idiomatic to test for the wanted functions themselves, as opposed to the identity of the library implementation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger, there are behavior differences that depends on processor architecture and libc implementation. Available functions isn't really good test, for example, `backtrace` function for MIPS exists but it is a stub

Comment: Again, it is best to test the actual behavior you are interested in.  If that's not just the availability of a given function but also its effects, then so be it.  It is absolutely possible to write autoconf tests that probe function behavior.  Autoconf even comes with several such tests built in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to detect what libc is installed in Linux distro?

The Autotools have no built-in mechanism for identifying the C library implementation, and I don't know any good, portable way to programmatically make such a determination in general.

But it seems that what you really want to know is whether certain functions exist and have behavior satisfying a particular criterion.  It is best and most idiomatic to test such things directly, rather than relying on proxies such as CPU architecture and standard library family.  In this case, it's probably easier, too.  Among the benefits are that

- you don't need to compile or maintain data about which proxy indicators predict your desired behavior, and in particular, you don't risk such data being wrong or falling out of date; and
- it's much clearer what the real build requirements are that you're trying to satisfy.

You raised `backtrace()` as an example. In this case, you could [generate a simple test program](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/html_node/Writing-Test-Programs.html) that calls that function, checks its output, and indicates via its exit status whether it meets your requirement.  You could first check for its existence first with [`AC_CHECK_FUNC`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/html_node/Generic-Functions.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fFUNC) and / or check for the existence of its header with [`AC_CHECK_HEADER`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/html_node/Generic-Headers.html#index-AC_005fCHECK_005fHEADER), but that's probably unnecessary because the tests those will perform are a subset of what you want to follow up with.  Specifically, you're probably looking for [`AC_RUN_IFELSE`](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/html_node/Runtime.html#index-AC_005fRUN_005fIFELSE).  For example,

```bash
AC_MSG_CHECKING([[whether backtrace() exists and works]])
AC_RUN_IFELSE([
  AC_LANG_PROGRAM([[
    #include <execinfo.h>
  ]], [[
    void *buffer[2];
    exit(!(1 == backtrace(buffer, 2)));
  ]])
], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([yes])
  # shell code to execute in this case (possibly including other Autoconf macros), maybe:
  backtrace_works=1
], [
  AC_MSG_RESULT([no])
  # shell code to execute in this case (possibly including other Autoconf macros), maybe:
  backtrace_works=0
])
```

You could put such code directly in your `configure.ac`, or wrap it in [an external macro definition](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.72/html_node/Writing-Autoconf-Macros.html) and put just an invocation of that macro in `configure.ac`.